# Whats the difference between single() and first() in Kotlin flows?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

Whats the difference between single() and first() in Kotlin flows? Can you give some examples on when to use what variant?

Comment: have you read docs? [single](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/single.html), [first](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/first.html)

Comment: Well, I just didnt get it from the documentation ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question.

`first()` will collect the first element of the flow.

```
val f = flow {
    var i = 0
    while (true) {
        emit(i)
        i = i.inc()
    }
}.first() // 0
```

`single()` will **wait until the flow is closed** and returns the one element it must contain for this method to execute successfully. If the flow is empty or has more than one element it will throw an exception.

```
callbackFlow {
    send("Hello World")
    close()
}.single() // "Hello World"
```